# Importing Existing QT C++ Project with its own Makefile in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt4, makefile

I would like to import an C++ GUI Project with its own Makefile in Eclipse. 
In the command prompt, everything works fine. But when I import the project, it gives an error

```
make all 

make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

Would be glad, if you give me an idea where I am going wrong.

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: You would have to show the makefile. Does it have the target `all`?

Comment: Well, I donot have a Makefile in the root directory, but individual Makefiles in the subdirectories. And Eclipse is not using these Makefile in the subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you import the project? I have used Eclipse with existing makefile projects a couple of times by *creating* a new empty makefile project and overriding the location of the project to refer to where the Makefile is present. It warns that the directory already exists, but it works fine.

Comment: May be I do not have the Makefile in the root directory. Is it possible to override it to use the Makefile from the sub directories. ??

Comment: I have not really invested too much time in working around it, as it worked for me. The simplest hack would be adding a makefile in the root directory for the project that will just call make on the internal directory. Else, you can create different C++ projects for each one of the subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Makefile has an "all" target.

A typical all target rule could look like

```
all: ../bin/myApplicationName
    @true
```

You'll probably also want to include a rule for clean if you don't already have one.

```
clean: 
    @-rm -f ../bin/myApplicationName *.o *.d
```